# How to integrate the shipping system in an App with React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, e-commerce, shipping-method

I developed an e-commerce app with React Native for Android and iOS and I already have almost everything that is needed to work but it does not have a shipping system (tracking) and I don't know how to do it.
Do shipping companies like Fedex or DHL have a special system for it?

I appreciate any resource or course that helps me find a solution to my problem.

Resource (links) or course(s) that helps me find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some shipping companies provide tracking apis

- fedex: https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/home.html
- UPS: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US
- DHL: https://developer.dhl.com/

These shipping companies have specific requirements and procedures for accessing their APIs, so be sure to read their documentation carefully.

Alternatively, you can consider using a shipping API aggregator service like Shippo (https://goshippo.com/), which allows you to access multiple shipping carriers through a single API.

Libraries:

- UPS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ups-api
- DHL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dhl-node
- Shippo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shippo
- multiple delivery companies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/delivery-tracker

Comment: I had already consulted some of these pages, they are confusing to me, in addition to being limiting because I live in Mexico, I also contacted me by mail with fedex and DHL but they did not respond.
I'll deal with Shippo, thank you very much.